# Error code : server OCIEnvNLSCreate failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracle11g

While running the .Net code in Windows OS I am getting the system exception

Error:

> server  OCIEnvNlSCreate failed with return code -1 but error message
> text was not available.

Comment: What driver are you using.  The driver and version of oracle have to be compatible.  It is best with Oracle to use their driver and not a vendor driver.  The syntax of the query has to work with a driver you are using.